# How to implode array elements to include a new line in a textarea?

Tags: php

I am trying to take an array made up of links and implode them into strings that will be displayed in a textarea for users to copy from.

This an example of the array:

```
<?php
$links = array('https://google.com','https://yahoo.com','https://msn.com');
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
echo '<textarea>' . implode("\n", $links) . '</textarea>';
echo '<textarea>' . implode(PHP_EOL, $links) . '</textarea>';
echo '<textarea>' . implode("\r\n", $links) . '</textarea>';
?>
```

When I attempt to use the "\n" to create a string that outputs each link in the array on a new line in the textarea, they still all run together in one continuous string like this:

```
https://google.comhttps://yahoo.comhttps://msn.com
```

Any thoughts on how to get the expected results of:

```
https://google.com
https://yahoo.com
https://msn.com
```

Comment: [`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or just implode with `<br>` directly

Comment: After correcting `EOL"` to `PHP_EOL` all three work for me.

Comment: @msg - this code will add a <br> to the outputted <textarea>.

Comment: You're actually looking at the output with a browser? Which one?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I just ran the code through a phpfiddle and I see that it does work. It must be something in my template engine that is rendering the "\n" incorrectly.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware using Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: OK, that's quite a normal browser and OS. Ah, that's funny, I used phpfiddle as well. Yes, something must be affecting the output.